# How can I see the actual line or word level differences when viewing merge conflicts in VS Code

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, git-merge

If "git merge .." results in a conflict, I can open the conflicted file in VS Code and see the diffs surrounded by <<<<<. ======, and >>>>> etc. But what I want to see are the *actual* differences between the two sections separated by =====, in the style of Meld or WinMerge, that is what words or lines are in one section and not the other. Is there a way to get this either in VS Code itself or another tool? (I'm aware of the Compare Changes option but all that does is show the differing sections side by side instead of on top of each other)

Comment: I know nothing of VS here, but from the command line, you can use `git mergetool` to invoke any arbitrary three-way merge tool. Given that VS seems to have an infinite number of plug-ins available, there are probably infinitely many plugins that do that as well, but that's automatically off topic on StackOverflow...

Comment: What I do when I can't spot the difference is copy each version of the conflicted area into a BBEdit document and then say Compare Two Front Documents.

Answer (score 0):

VS Code now (in sept 2022 version - probably even sooner) has a "[Merge editor](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_72#_merge-editor)". After opening the file containing the conflict, you have to click a button in lower right reading "Resolve in Merge Editor" to get there.

PS: Annoyingly, at least for me, it does not show line changes, but considers a whole file as one changed block. However, from the screenshots on MS page, this is not an expected behavior.